# Show in Hilbert space: $\|T(h)\| \geq C \|h\|$ for all $h \in (\operatorname{Ker}T)^\perp$ for closed range operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I need your help in the following task:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $T \in L(H,H)$ have a closed range.
>
> Show that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|T(h)\| \geq C \|h\|$ for all $h \in (\operatorname{Ker}T)^\perp$.

I just collected some properties since I don't know how to solve the problem.

Let $K = \operatorname{Ker}T$. I know that $K$ is a closed subspace of $H$ since $T$ is linear and bounded, hence continuous. $K$ can be written as $K = T^{-1}(\{0\})$, so it is a preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ under a continuous function, hence it is closed.

Since $K$ is closed subspace, I can apply the projection theorem and I get that every $x \in H$ can be uniquely written as $x=x_K + x_{K^\perp}$ with $x_K \in K$ and $x_{K^\perp} \in K^\perp$.

If I now take an arbitrary $h \in K^\perp$ it can be written as $h = x - x_K$ where $x \in H$ and $x_K \in K$. Moreover I get $T(h)=T(x-x_k)=T(x)-T(x_K) = T(x)$ because $x_K \in K$.

In addition I thought about the basic definition of a bounded operator, which states that there is some constant $D>0$ such that $\|T(x)\| \leq D |\|x\|$ for all $x \in H$.

This would give $\|T(h)\| = \|T(x)\| \leq D \|x\| $, but this doesn't help me.

I also thought about using the operator norm of $T$ which would give the inequality $\|T(x)\| \leq \|T\|_{op}||x|| $

Moreover I don't know how to include the assumption that $T$ has closed range.

I hope you can give me some good hints or help me rearranging the facts above to get a smooth proof.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_range_theorem applied for the restriction of $T_1$ from the Hilbert space $K^\perp$ to the image $T(H)$, which is a Hilbert space, too, being a closed subspace of a Hilbert space. Then the inverse is continuous, this inverse is bounded, so $T_1$ is bounded from below.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Define $S: H|Ker (T) \to T(H)$ by $S(x+Ker (T))=Tx$. Verify that this is bijective continuous linear map. By Open Mapping Theorem its inverse is continuous. Now verify that the sated inequality holds with $C=\|S^{-1}\|$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the image of $T$ is closed, the restriction of $T$ to the orthogonal of $Ker(T)$ that we call  $U$ is a continuous bounded map between Banach spaces. The open mapping theorem implies that it is invertible. For every $x\in U, \|T^{-1}(T(y))\|=\|y\|\leq D\|T(y)\|$. Take $D={1\over C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the map
$$ \tilde{T}:H/\mathrm{Ker}(T) \to \mathrm{Range}(T), [h]\mapsto \tilde{T}([h])=T(h). $$
Because $T$ has closed range, then $\tilde{T}$ is a continuous bijection from the Banach space $H/\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ to the Banach space $\mathrm{Range}(T)$. The norm on the second space is simply the restriction of the norm from $H$, whilst on the first space we are considering
$$ \| [h]\|_{H/\mathrm{Ker}(T)} = \inf_{k\in \mathrm{Ker}(T)} \|h+k\|. $$
In particular, if $h\in \mathrm{Ker}(T)^\perp$ we have
$$ \|h+k\|^2 = \|h\|^2+\|k\|^2 + 2\langle h,k\rangle = \|h\|^2+\|k\|^2, $$
which means that
$$ \| [h]\|_{H/\mathrm{Ker}(T)} = \|h\|. $$
By the open mapping theorem, $\tilde{T}$ has a continuous inverse.

For every $h\in \mathrm{Ker}(T)^\perp$ we have
$$ \|h\|_H = \|[h]\|_{H/\mathrm{Ker}(T)} = \|\tilde{T}^{-1}( \tilde{T}(h))\|_{H/\mathrm{Ker}(T)} \leq C \|T(h)\|_{\mathrm{Range}(T)} = C \|T(h)\|. $$

Comment: What do you exactly mean by $[h]$? Is it the $h \in KerT$ in the decomposition of an element $x \in H$ into $x = h + h_\perp$ with $h \in KerT$ and $h_\perp \in (KerT)^\perp$ ?

Comment: Exactly, for $[h]$ I mean the equivalence class of $h\in H$ in the quotient space $H/\mathrm{Ker}(T)$.